# Slow Boot Ubuntu even on SSD

Tags: hp

My Ubuntu was working fine. It was booting in about 5-6 seconds. Earlier, HP logo used to remove and Ubuntu logo appeared on the screen within 1-2 seconds and then I was at my lock screen in no time.
But now, my screen is getting stuck on HP screen for about 40-55 seconds and then Ubuntu screen is appearing.
I am running systemd-analyze blame. The result is fine as I can see that Ubuntu is not taking time. It is HP who is taking a lot of time. Earlier, HP screen used to go away within 1-2 seconds. But now, it is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question myself as I have got the solution. I just updated initramfs and Ubuntu is finally booting fine.

> sudo update-initramfs -u